# Legend over graphs

Tags: pgfplots

The following code makes the legend over the plot (and the size of the plot is too small):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,
                backgrounds, bending,
                calc, chains,
                %decorations.pathmorphing,
                fit,
                %petri,
                positioning,
                trees,
                quotes,
                shapes.misc}

\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{31,22,70}
\definecolor{darkblue2}{RGB}{21,126,251}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,intersections,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{wrapfig}


\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \begin{axis}[
                        title={x},
                        xlabel={xx},
                        ylabel={Temps [$Secondes$]},
                        xmin=0, xmax=1000,
                        ymin=0, ymax=25,
                        xtick={20,100,200,500,1000},
                        ytick={0,5,10,15,20,25},
                        legend pos=north west,
                        ymajorgrids=true,
                        grid style=dashed,
                    ]    
                \addplot[
                  color=red,
                  mark=halfcircle*,
                ]
                coordinates {(0,0) (5,5)(50,7)(100,9)(200,9)(500,9.5)(750,9)(1000,9.5)};
                \legend{xx}

                \addplot[
                  color=cyan,
                  mark=halfcircle*,
                ]
                coordinates {(0,0) (5,5)(50,12)(100,25)(200,20)(500,15)(750,20)(1000,27)};
                \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=Hplot}\addlegendentry{xx}
               \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
              \caption{A gull}
            \end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

How can I fix that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scale your graph through the axis options `width=<width>` and `height=<height>`. Other possibility is to use a `\resizebox {\textwidth}{\height}` inside the `wrapfigure`. Keep in mind that `\resizebox` scales the font size inside your `tikzpicture`, too. Nevertheless, if you use these solutions with `wrapfigure` you have to take care of its width as well.

You can tune the position of the legend with `legend style={at={(<x>,<y>)},anchor=<name>}`

Output `wrapfigure` and axis options:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,
                backgrounds, bending,
                calc, chains,
                %decorations.pathmorphing,
                fit,
                %petri,
                positioning,
                trees,
                quotes,
                shapes.misc}

\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{31,22,70}
\definecolor{darkblue2}{RGB}{21,126,251}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,intersections,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{wrapfig}


\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{1.0\textwidth}
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \begin{axis}[
                        width=\textwidth,
                        height=\axisdefaultheight,
                        title={x},
                        xlabel={xx},
                        ylabel={Temps [$Secondes$]},
                        xmin=0, xmax=1000,
                        ymin=0, ymax=25,
                        xtick={20,100,200,500,1000},
                        ytick={0,5,10,15,20,25},
%                        legend pos=north west,
                        legend style={at={(1.05,1.0)},anchor=north}, % legend pos=outer north east,
                        ymajorgrids=true,
                        grid style=dashed,
                    ]    
                \addplot[
                  color=red,
                  mark=halfcircle*,
                ]
                coordinates {(0,0) (5,5)(50,7)(100,9)(200,9)(500,9.5)(750,9)(1000,9.5)};
                \legend{xx}

                \addplot[
                  color=cyan,
                  mark=halfcircle*,
                ]
                coordinates {(0,0) (5,5)(50,12)(100,25)(200,20)(500,15)(750,20)(1000,27)};
                \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=Hplot}\addlegendentry{xx}
               \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
              \caption{A gull}
            \end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

Output `wrapfigure` and `resizebox`:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,
                backgrounds, bending,
                calc, chains,
                %decorations.pathmorphing,
                fit,
                %petri,
                positioning,
                trees,
                quotes,
                shapes.misc}

\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{31,22,70}
\definecolor{darkblue2}{RGB}{21,126,251}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,intersections,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{wrapfig}


\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{1.0\textwidth}
                \resizebox {\textwidth}{!} {
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \begin{axis}[
                      %  width=\textwidth,
                       % height=\axisdefaultheight,
                        title={x},
                        xlabel={xx},
                        ylabel={Temps [$Secondes$]},
                        xmin=0, xmax=1000,
                        ymin=0, ymax=25,
                        xtick={20,100,200,500,1000},
                        ytick={0,5,10,15,20,25},
                      % legend pos=north west,
                        legend style={at={(1.15,1.0)},anchor=north}, % legend pos=outer north east,
                        ymajorgrids=true,
                        grid style=dashed,
                    ]    
                \addplot[
                  color=red,
                  mark=halfcircle*,
                ]
                coordinates {(0,0) (5,5)(50,7)(100,9)(200,9)(500,9.5)(750,9)(1000,9.5)};
                \legend{xx}

                \addplot[
                  color=cyan,
                  mark=halfcircle*,
                ]
                coordinates {(0,0) (5,5)(50,12)(100,25)(200,20)(500,15)(750,20)(1000,27)};
                \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=Hplot}\addlegendentry{xx}
               \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }
              \caption{A gull}
            \end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot :)